# Notepad++ RegEx, convert a string in a substring of another text

Tags: regex, notepad++

Sorry, I didn't know how to ask question in a clearer way (I'm open to advices).
Here's my problem

I have this sequences of strings:

```
string1
string2
string3
...
```

which I want to turn into

```
if(eventData.string1) me.string1 = eventData.string1;
if(eventData.string2) me.string2 = eventData.string2;
if(eventData.string3) me.string3 = eventData.string3;
...
```

I have tried this

```
\.*   --> if\(eventData\.$1\) me\.$1 = eventData\.$1;
```

but it didn't worked because I had this result:

```
if(eventData.) me. = eventData.;Sif(eventData.) me. = eventData.;eif(eventData.) me. = eventData.;i....
```

Answer (score -1):

Pattern:

```
^string\d+
```

Replacement:

```
if(eventData.$0) me.$0 = eventData.$0;
```

Comment: Sorry, I get "no occurence was found"

Comment: You should explain the answer more so people can understand the answer

Comment: @AminahNuraini it's a question about REGEX. I would have thought the context to which I reference 'pattern' and 'replacement' was, therefore, obvious.

Comment: @SamK - it sounds like you're searching literally rather than via REGEX. Make sure REGEX is switched on. If there's a separate option to enable multi-line patterns, enable this. (In sublime, this is on for default for REGEX searches.)

Comment: @Utkanos no, I wasn't searching literally, but the this is my strings aren't "really" string1, string2... but those where examples. They are strings with different chars. But I got my solution thanks to yours. I posted it above

Comment: Glad you got there in the end. Please consider an upvote if you feel my solution led you to your eventual one.

Comment: @Utkanos, it was moderators's request to maintain quality. Always make the answer pleasant to read

Answer (score -1):

I've found the solution using previous answer

```
^.*
```

Replace with

```
if\(eventData\.$0\) me\.$0 = eventData\.$0;
```